# twitter api in c# without pop authorize dialog

Tags: c#, twitter

I want to write a console app that runs as a background task that searches twitter.

I want the job to kick off without popping up an authorize dialog. Is there a way I can call the twitter api without any dialog popping up?

I just found out that I need to use Application Only authentication.  Where can I find a good example of application only authentication

Comment: What APIs have you tried? The popup may be a mandatory feature of the Twitter API v1.1.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I don't think Twitter has long-lived access tokens.

Comment: I guess my question is, do I have to authorize interactively? or can my console app authorize automatically without any user interaction?

Comment: @David Twitter does have long-lived access tokens. No problem to store and reuse them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Single User Authorization or a newer featured called Application-Only authorization. Here's an example of how to do Application Only with [LINQ to Twitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/):

```
    private static void HandleApplicationOnlyAuthentication()
    {
        var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
            {
                ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
                ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"]
            }
        };

        auth.Authorize();
        //auth.Invalidate();

        var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

        var srch =
            (from search in twitterCtx.Search
             where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                   search.Query == "LINQ to Twitter"
             select search)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine("\nQuery: {0}\n", srch.SearchMetaData.Query);
        srch.Statuses.ForEach(entry =>
            Console.WriteLine(
                "ID: {0, -15}, Source: {1}\nContent: {2}\n",
                entry.StatusID, entry.Source, entry.Text));
    }
```

The call to Invalidate is commented out, but you'll want to put a timer on that and Twitter's rule of thumb is to invalidate the bearer token every 15 minutes or so.

The LINQ to Twitter site has documentation on [Single User Authorization](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single%20User%20Authorization&referringTitle=Learning%20to%20use%20OAuth) too. There's a [Samples](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20Samples&referringTitle=Home) page on the site and the [downloadable source code](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt) has working demos. BTW, Twitter user tokens generally don't ever expire, so you can store and continue to use the same tokens.

Comment: the linqto twitter does not support v1.1 of the api

Comment: @magic-c0d3r LINQ to Twitter does support v1.1 of Twitter API. It was the first .NET library to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Joe, works like a CHARM! Thanks a lot for you efforts to build such elegant solution on top of not so friendly REST interface. Still looking for different search criteria :)

Answer (score -1):

No, your console app cannot authorize without user interaction.  The whole point of authorization is that users have to take action to allow applications to use their accounts.

Trust me, you really wouldn't want any application to be able to take control of your Twitter account without your explicit permission. :)

Comment: This isn't totally correct. I just posted code to show how a console app can authorize without interaction. Your second point is valid though and indicates and underlying concept of why OAuth is necessary. However, it misses the premise of his basic requirement to "Perform Searches" in the background, which shouldn't require a user interaction.